# Store and retrieve Google Dart objects in JavaScript library containers

Tags: javascript, dart

**Store and retrieve Google Dart objects in JavaScript library containers**

In a Dart application I am using an external JavaScript library to do various matrix calculations.

The specific functionality of the library is not important, what it's important is that I need to store and retrieve Dart object that I put in the matrix.

**Dart Class** - Lets image i have a dart object that which has a parameter called name

```
MyDartClass mydc = new MyDartClass(something, something);
mydc.name;
// Everything works as planned
```

**Storing**

```
matrix = js.context.matrix
matrix.cell(1,1).store("thing", new MyDartClass(something, something));
```

**Retrieving**

```
matrix.cell(1,1).has_object_of_type("thing");
// true
MyDartClass mydc = matrix.cell(1,1).retrieve("thing");
```

**Do something with the object**

```
mydc.name;
// Exception: The null object does not have a getter 'name'.
// NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'name'
// Receiver: null
// Arguments: []
```

**Does the library really work?**
Yes it does. I have done the exact same thing in pure javascript many times and there are plenty of test to test the behaviour ( in Javascript )

**Is Dart Broken?**
When I try to use a javascriptified Hash to do the same behavoiur it works like a charm.

```
  var options = js.map({ 'dart' : new MyDartclass(something, something));
  var y = options["dart"];
  js.context.console.log(y.name);
  // Name is printed
```

**What do you get out from the retrieve?**
It seems that I get some kind of Dart Proxy

```
    MyDartClass mydc = matrix.cell(1,1). retrieve("thing");
    js.context.console.log(mydc);

DartProxy {id: "dart-ref-20", port: DartSendPortSync}
id: "dart-ref-20"
port: DartSendPortSync
__proto__: DartProxy
```

I belive that the lib stores the objects, deep down, in a hash map. But it seems like when I retrieve the object into the Dart I get something, but not in a way that I can work with it. So i need **help** since I don't know how to make it work.

- Do I need to de-proxify the object?
- Perhaps it IS a Dart bug when you try to retrieve objects from hashes inside objects
- Perhaps I missunderstod everything that this is not suppose to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing and retrieving Dart objects inside the same scope is working. There's the following test case in [the tests of js-interop](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/blob/master/test/js/browser_tests.dart#L473-477) to proove it :

```dart
test('retrieve same dart Object', () {
  final date = new DateTime.now();
  js.context.dartDate = date;
  expect(js.context.dartDate, equals(date));
});
```

However there seems to be an issue with multiple scopes (and multiple event loops as well). There is no way to retain a dart object for now. So your dart object reference goes away at the end of scope. Here's a simple test case that fails :

```dart
test('retrieve same dart Object', () {
  final date = new DateTime.now();
  js.scoped(() {
    js.context.dartDate = date;
  });
  js.scoped(() {
    expect(js.context.dartDate, equals(date));
  });
});
```

Please [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/issues/new).

Comment: Hi Alexandre. Thanks for the answer. I created an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/issues/80. It's pretty much the second half of the answer and link back to this question. Best Regards Jonas